# Background video doesn't work on server

Tags: video, background

I designed a website using `<video>` tag to make a background video.

It works fine on my disk, but when I upload it on a server video does not show up.

It doesn't have anything to do with browser support, it works from my disk on the same browser that doesn't work when it's on a server.

Comment: Perhaps you could post a minimal example. Also be sure to check that the file permissions are correct on the server.

Comment: How to check file permissions?

Comment: If the server is running unix or linux, you can use the `ls -lad p` command, replacing `p` with the path of the directory containing the file.

Comment: Your question needs more details in it for it to be answerable, as well as useful for others in the future. Try going through the steps listed in one of the answers and either picking one of them as an answer if it works, or post the solution if you discover one that isn't mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Without more details, this could literally be anything, so if you can post a jsfiddle with your code that'd be helpful.

For what it's worth, here are three things I typically check when dealing with `<video>` issues:

### File/Folder Permissions

I've had issues with file permissions being altered during upload. Make sure both the video files and the folder are executable by users.

### Source Path

Try copying the src from the `<video>` tag into your browser and see if it shows up. Relative paths that work on your local computer don't necessarily work on a server.

### Codecs in .htaccess

Some browsers have trouble identifying video codecs, so it's always helpful to add the following to your `.htaccess` file:

```
AddType video/webm .webm
AddType video/ogg .ogv
AddType video/mp4 .mp4
```